# Lookup with InitialContext lookup() and @Inject of Singleton

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, dependency-injection, singleton

I have an @Singleton bean that I use to store state that is to be shared with other beans/threads. The state that is to be shared is maintained in a HashMap. Other beans that require the services of this Singleton simply do an @Inject and invoke the methods.

Recently, we had to introduce Quartz Scheduler since we had some asynchronous jobs to be done. In one quartz job I lookup the Singleton using IntialContext lookup(), and use methods provided by the Singleton. Once this job executes, the other beans that use @Inject (for the Singleton) no longer get information maintained in the HashMap.

```
@Singleton(mappedName = "ClientSessionMgr")
public class ClientSessionMgr {

    private final Map<String, ClientSession> clientSessions = new HashMap<String, ClientSession>();

    /* Methods that manage the clientSessions data */
}
```

One amongst a few beans that Inject the above Singleton.

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "NwdCredProfRepo")
public class NwdCredProfRepo {

  @Inject private ClientSessionMgr csm;

  /* Bean Methods that invoke some methods of the singleton */
}
```

The Quartz Job that does a lookup of the singleton and then uses the methods provided by the same.

```
public class ClientSyncProbe implements Job {
  private ClientSessionMgr csm;

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
      InitialContent ic = new InitialContext();
      csm = (ClientSessionMgr) ic.lookup("java:app/SVWeb/ClientSessionMgr");

      /* Some tasks, and finally */
      ic.close()
  }
}
```

I am guessing that I am missing a pattern principle. Any help?

Comment: Why Quartz instead of `@Schedule`?

Comment: How are the @Stateless beans being used?  Where/how are they being injected?

Comment: JNDI lookups may not behave in the way that you think they should when executed from random threads not controlled by the application server, such as those used by Quartz. Use `@Schedule` and injection instead

Comment: Let me use @Schedule instead